# How to implement WCF server-side retries

Tags: wcf

I want to add server-side retry behavior if something specific happens during operation.

Custom IOperationInvoker looks like a good candidate for this functionality, but...

Unfortunately instance on which operation should be performed is already created/resolved, so to correctly implement retry logic everyone should write stateless service implementations which is quite limiting, sometimes it's nice to have InstanceContextMode.PerCall mode and state which lives only during request lifetime.

Is there any place or possibility to force WCF to re-create/resolve service and invoke operation again?

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail why you need the retry logic and why you decided to implement it on server-side?

Comment: I do not see the logic of "Unfortunately instance on which operation should be performed is already created/resolved, so to correctly implement retry logic everyone should write stateless service". Why can't you retry using the same service instance? Has its internal state mutated in an unrecoverable way? If so how? A more detailed example is needed.

Comment: @ErnieL as I mentioned in my question, requiring implementation to be stateless or, even harder, exception-safe is quite limiting. In my case service implementation resolved from IoC container with dependencies which use ORM, which state is corrupted after exception and can't be reused.

Comment: @MaksymStrukov I also ask myself the same question... I thought it would be easy, but now with all troubles I've encountered I don't see any benefits having this implemented on server-side.

Comment: In fact I can't see any troubles at all to implement it on the server side I just wanted more info about the problem to come up with a neat solution. Ok, I'll write one soon. You might consider it.

Answer (score 0):

Not so easy to imlement retry logic on your own. You will have to deal with a number of issues like those:

1. What if all attempts failed?
2. Should there be an interval between attempts?
3. What if you server is down between the first and second attempt?
4. etc.

Fortunately there is an out of the box solution which already does everything for you. Take a look at the MSMQ WCF binding.

1. It will put you contract object to the dead letter queue if you wish, so you can easyly keep track of such messages and even force to process them again.
2. You can set an interval between the attempts. So if you server is down for 10 minutes not all attempts are shot.
3. You can configure it to be durable. It will store the messages on disk, So when your server is back it will try to process the message again.
4. Etc. Take a look at the MSMQ binding you will find a lot of useful features.
   Here's a good article about the [queuing in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx)

So in the long run your design will be something like that:

Client Call -> MSMQ -> Service

Please note you don't have to make any changes to the code you have now at all, you just change the binding configuration and set up MSMQ which is fairly easy.

Just in case you can't use msmq binding directly with you client, you can always go with an special server side service which just puts the messages to the queue. So the design will be:

Client service -> HTTP -> QueueService (one method which puts messages to a queue) -> MSMQ -> ProcessService

Hope it helps!

Comment: You didn't understand me or I wasn't able to express myself. I do know things which should be taken into account when doing retries. My question was pure technical - given one of the WCF RPC bindings (Http/Tcp/whatever), what is the best place to inject into WCF server-side infrastructure to be able to retry invocation on new instance, if instance context mode is PerCall. Hope this time it is clear.

Comment: Well you need retry logic when the instance of you service is recreated with each attempt, right? So you just configur your instance mode as PerCall and then with each attempt to process a message from MSMQ it will create a new service instance

Comment: @MaksymStukov as I said it's not possible to change binding, it must be RPC. Let's say because this is query request from Web front-end. We do use queues and messaging for commands, but we don't use queues for queries when latency and response time is vital, right?